# Concatenation of strings does not work

Tags: bash, awk

```
DASqv -v -H$H -c$cov $db $i | grep Recommend - | sed "s|Recommend ||g" - | sed "s|'||g" -` by itself produces `DAStrim -g20 -b25
```

My goal is to combine the previous results with `awk '{print $1 " " $2 " "$3 " $db $i"}'` and pipe the whole command to an output file `> $(basename $i .las).DAStrim`.

Unfortunately, I only get as result `bananaDB ./bananaDB.100.las` and not `DAStrim -g20 -b25 bananaDB ./bananaDB.100.las` with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

db=bananaDB
H=6973
cov=38

for i in $(find . -type f -name "*.*.las");
do
  #cat <<EOF
  qsub <<EOF

#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -N DASqv
#PBS -l walltime=48:00:00
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -l mem=1G
#PBS -l ncpus=1
#PBS -M m.lorenc@qut.edu.au
##PBS -m bea

cd \$PBS_O_WORKDIR

source activate thegenemyers


DASqv -v -H$H -c$cov $db $i | grep Recommend - | sed "s|Recommend ||g" - | sed "s|'||g" - | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " "$3 " $db $i"}' > $(basename $i .las).DAStrim

EOF

done
```

**UPDATE**

```
DASqv -v -H$H -c$cov $db $i
```

produced:

```
DASqv -c38 bananaDB ./bananaDB.100.las

Input:   16,450reads,   210,758,575 bases (another 9,934 were < H-length)

Histogram of q-values (average 10 best)

                 Input                 QV

    50:    1494189    0.2%       380302   18.0%

    49:     364713    0.0%          484    0.0%
    48:     545846    0.1%          423    0.1%
    47:     650479    0.2%          466    0.1%
    46:     835282    0.3%          548    0.1%
    45:    1054589    0.4%          648    0.1%
    44:    1299423    0.5%          775    0.2%
    43:    1644281    0.7%          895    0.2%
    42:    2036915    0.9%         1193    0.3%
    41:    2571126    1.2%         1334    0.4%
    40:    3518594    1.5%         1647    0.5%
    39:    3641660    1.9%         2046    0.6%
    38:    5026473    2.4%         2291    0.7%
    37:    6243982    3.1%         2708    0.9%
    36:    7600704    3.9%         3301    1.1%
    35:    9313754    4.9%         4002    1.3%
    34:   11257936    6.0%         4676    1.6%
    33:   13508338    7.5%         5544    1.9%
    32:   15981847    9.1%         6552    2.3%
    31:   18648809   11.1%         7771    2.7%
    30:   22290239   13.4%         9124    3.3%
    29:   25083448   16.0%        10624    3.9%
    28:   29566164   19.1%        12874    4.6%
    27:   33339712   22.6%        15482    5.5%
    26:   37891335   26.6%        18869    6.6%
    25:   44146531   31.2%        23307    7.9%
    24:   44948068   35.9%        28142    9.5%
    23:   50951224   41.3%        33590   11.5%
    22:   55009718   47.1%        42157   13.9%
    21:   57456151   53.1%        52181   16.9%
    20:   60635065   59.4%        63207   20.6%
    19:   58423422   65.6%        76426   25.0%
    18:   58472922   71.7%        91565   30.2%
    17:   55127848   77.5%       107289   36.4%
    16:   50395382   82.7%       123758   43.6%
    15:   43893354   87.3%       136465   51.4%
    14:   36509552   91.2%       145632   59.8%
    13:   28654550   94.2%       145540   68.2%
    12:   21245809   96.4%       138232   76.2%
    11:   14560980   97.9%       121403   83.2%
    10:    9345155   98.9%        98071   88.8%
     9:    5395169   99.5%        73996   93.1%
     8:    2894210   99.8%        52246   96.1%
     7:    1335673   99.9%        33845   98.0%
     6:     581470  100.0%        19476   99.2%
     5:     201756  100.0%         9367   99.7%
     4:      76322  100.0%         3760   99.9%
     3:      18979  100.0%         1082  100.0%
     2:       4751  100.0%          264  100.0%
     1:        456  100.0%           41  100.0%
     0:       2686  100.0%           38  100.0%

  Recommend 'DAStrim -g20 -b25'
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possibly related: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: I suspect it might have to do with the `$db` and `$i` variables in your `awk` command.  What about: `awk -v db="$db" -v i="$i" '{print $1,$2,$3,$db,$i}'`?

Comment: Also I don't think `$(basename $i .las)` is correct, not that it would be your issue but it should just be `$(basename "$i")`

Comment: awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,bananaDB,./bananaDB.100.las}
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,bananaDB,./bananaDB.100.las}
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,bananaDB,./bananaDB.100.las}
awk: cmd. line:1:          ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,bananaDB,./bananaDB.100.las}
awk: cmd. line:1:                    ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,bananaDB,./bananaDB.100.las}
awk: cmd. line:1:                      ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,bananaDB,./bananaDB.100.las}

Comment: sorry I'm not sure.

Comment: You are making this far more complicated than it needs to be.  What is the output of `DASqv -v -H$H -c$cov $db $i` **before** it is piped into grep|sed|sed|awk?   Do not reply in a comment, edit your question and add the requested information there.

Comment: added the output

Comment: do you want the submitted job to just output `DAStrim -g20 -b25 bananadb ./bananaDB.100.las` to `./bananaDB.100.DAStrim` or to actually **run** that command and redirect the output to `./bananaDB.100.DAStrim`?  The script in my answer assumes the former but can easily be changed to do the latter.

Comment: only to create the command and not running it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making things more difficult than they need to be, and running into white-space and quoting issues.  Try something like the following:

**Step 1:** create a standalone script that does what you want with one or more of your data file(s), given the appropriate args and filename(s) on the command line.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# use the first 3 arguments for the values to pass to DASqv
db="$1"
H="$2"
cov="$3"

# use shift to get rid of them once we have them in variables, ...
shift 3

# ... so we can loop over the remaining filenames (1 or more) on the command line
for filename in "$@" ; do
  outfile="$(basename "$filename" .las).DAStrim"
  qsub <<EOF
#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -N DASqv
#PBS -l walltime=48:00:00
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -l mem=30G
#PBS -l ncpus=1
#PBS -M m.lorenc@qut.edu.au
##PBS -m bea

cd "\$PBS_O_WORKDIR"

source activate thegenemyers

DASqv -v -H"$H" -c"$cov" "$db" "$filename" | 
  sed -n -e '/Recommend/ {
               s/Recommend //;
               s/\x27//g;
               s:$: "$db" "$filename":;
               p
             }' > "$outfile"

EOF

done
```

(the `sed` script in the middle of that could be all on one line but the extra line-feeds and indentation make it more readable without changing what it does / how it runs in any way.  Also, note the use of `\x27` to remove all single-quote characters.  `0x27` is the hexadecimal notation for the ASCII single-quote character)

save it as e.g. `submit-jobs.sh` and make it executable with `chmod +x submit-job.sh`.

**Step 2:** Test it

Test that the script does what you want by manually using it to submit jobs.  e.g. run:

```
/path/to/submit-jobs.sh bananaDB 6973 38 /path/to/somefile.las
```

Modify the script if necessary until it does exactly what you want.

**Step 3:** Now use `find` to submit multiple jobs using the script:

```
find . -type f -name '*.las' -exec /path/to/submit-jobs.sh bananaDB 6973 38 {} +
```

**Step 4:** (optional) turn step 3 into a script that you can run with different arguments to save you from having to type the `find ...` command every time you want another run with slightly different values.  e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f -name '*.las' -exec /path/to/submit-jobs.sh "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

If you saved this as `find-and-submit.sh` and made it executable with `chmod +x`, you would run it as:

```
find-and-submit.sh bananaDB 6973 38
```

This step 4 script could even have a for loop for the variables so that, for example, it submitted jobs for `$cov` values from 35 to 45 instead of requiring `$cov` to be one of the arguments.

Comment: I got `sed: -e expression #1, char 112: unknown option to `s'`

Comment: BTW, one other common problem when submitting jobs to PBS or Torque or  slurm etc is that the environment when the job is executed may be quite different to the command line environment when you submitted the job.   e.g. if the `activate` file sourced into the submitted script isn't in `$PBS_O_WORKDIR` then the job wil fail.

Comment: found what the problem is.  my tests were on files in the current dir, so there were no `/` characters in any filename.  When there are / characters (e.g. when used with find), that breaks the sed command which adds the filename to the DAStrim command.  I'll fix it by using `:` as the delimiter on that line.

Comment: What does `shift 3` mean?

Comment: `shift` dumps the first positional parameter and then renumbers the parameters remaining so that what was $2 is now $1, $3 is now $2, etc.   `shift 3` dumps the first three parameters.   try `help shift` in bash, or `man bash` and search for `shift \[n\]` for more details.

Comment: BTW, i've slightly improved the script.  Works the same, but should be easier to read/understand.  The sed part of the script now uses `\x27`, the hexadecimal ASCII code for a single-quote.  This allows the entire sed script to be single-quoted, eliminating the need to backslash-escape the double-quotes.